# Repairing Polybutylene leak

Tags: plumbing, leak

So I found my floor/wall getting wet, ripped off the drywall and found a dripping poly joint.

I figure I can trim out the joint, and put in PEX.
But I'm guessing it would be better to rip it all out and PEX the entire thing, but I'll have to rip open a lot more wall.  What would be best practice?

[image: Leaky pipe]

Comment: Have you positively identified the tee as the leaking point. The tee is the low spot so water could be running down to it  from a point higher up and then dripping off of it.

Comment: Be careful. Now that you know you have PB, your homeowners insurance may not cover you if it fails. You've already got one leak. It's probably time to consider re-piping the entire house.

Comment: Verified the tee was the leak, ripped out all the 1/2" PB except the one going to the right, and put in PEX.  Re-piping is going to a be a big project with those copper pipes going into the slab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your only leaking area is what you see, then I would cut out only what you see and replace it. The problem with just replacing the "T" is that you will have to cut the pipes and that means shorter pipes and more adapters....more leaks later on possibly. I would cut about 3 inches from the right side that you see in the picture and as close and possible to the top of the "T" and remove all the stuff on the left all the way to the copper pipe. Replace all that with PEX. Or just cut your "T" out and shark-bite it.